# Intersection coordinates of two polygons

Tags: tcl

I have two polygons, and wanted to find the coordinates of the intersection polygon .  Using Tcl
I have tried with math geometry functions which returns boolean value if the two polygons intersect. But I want the coordinates of the polygon which comes when the two intersect

Comment: We can't help you unless you show us some code

Comment: The key resource to read about this is on the Tcler's Wiki: https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Polygon+intersection